# What is the value of $a+b$ where the area of the square in the diagram is $\dfrac{a}{b}$ and both are co-primes?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles

[image]

> The diagram shows two circles, each of radius $1$ and a square. The
>   side length of the square can be written as $\dfrac{a}{b}$ ($a$ and
>   $b$ are co-prime). Find $a+b$.

**Source: Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2013 Junior Category.**

The question only gives us the radius of the circle. Is this information enough? Is there any formula or way to get the area of the square from the radius of the circle only?

Comment: This information is enough, because there is only one such square. You don't need know the area (or the side) of that square as the question is only about `a + b`.

Comment: It's pretty clear there is only one square that touches those two circles at tangents.  If you can get the side from the radius from the circle only you can get the area from the circle only (and vice versa).  But why would you think you need to get the area?  Maybe you can get the side?

Comment: The side is $\frac ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are coprime is just a matter of saying the side is rational.  $a + b$ has no geometric or significant meaning.  It's just that if the side is $s$ and $s$ is rational $a+b$ is something you can calculate.  For example if the side is $.75 = \frac 34$ then $a+b = 7$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Let $A$ and $C$ be the centers of the circles, $B$ and $D$ the tangency points with the line. Denote furthermore the length of the square's side by $2k$.

Now extend $GH$ to meet $[AB]$ at $J$. By Pythagoras

> $$[AJ]^2+[JH]^2=[AH]^2\iff (1-2k)^2+(1-k)^2=1$$

I think you can end it now...